# Setting Bits in C Microcontroller

Tags: c, variable-assignment, microcontroller, bit

I'm attempting to learn how to program micro-controllers in C and have a question regarding bit assignments. Say for example I were to declare an 8 bit number.

```
binary_number = 0b00000000;
```

Now, lets say I wanted to set bit 3 only. Example texts I have seen use an operation like the following:

```
binary_number |= (1<<4)
```

Am I understanding this correctly? We are taking binary_number and `'or-ing'` it with essentially `0b00001000` and then assigning that outcome to binary_number?

Likewise, when resetting this bit:

```
binary_number &= ~(1<<4)
```

We are essentially taking binary_number (`0b00001000`) and `'and-ing'` it with `0b11110111` and then assigning `binary_number` to the outcome of that expression?

Do I understand this *correctly*?

Comment: As an additional comment (which is especially important if you are working directly on hardware), you should be aware that setting and clearing bits this way is always a read-modify-write operation. If you are doing this directly to hardware registers, it might well be that the reading part is already causing a side effect you want to avoid (depending on the hardware specs). You might use shadow copies of that registers in RAM if that's the case for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct! :)
but a little change...

For resetting or setting the bit 3, you need to left shift the 1 by 3 places only.
1<<4 : 0b00010000
1<<3 : 0b00001000

Use the bitwise OR operator (|) to set xth bit.

n |= 1 << x;

That will set bit x.

Use the bitwise AND operator (&) to reset xth  bit.

n &= ~(1 << x);

That will reset bit x.

Comment: Ahh yes, that was a stupid mistake on my part. And hopefully you will be able to answer a question that I just thought of. Is it correct to assume that using the |= statement is the equivalent of doing something like the following: number = number | bit_mask

Comment: @Teague, yes that's exactly what |= means.

Comment: @Teague,yes, |= is just like shorcut and it saves typing time :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are understanding it correctly. That is exactly what you have to do to set and unset bits. Looks pretty complicated I know but you could always write a helper function that you pack around with you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out others, you are setting/resetting the `4th` bit not the `3rd`

```
Set mask:     1<<4 =    10000 = 0001 0000
Reset Mask: ~(1<<4) = ~(10000)= ~(0001 0000) = 1110 1111
```

So, `binary_number |= (1<<4)`:

```
Original Number     -      0000 0000
Mask to set 4th bit - (OR) 0001 0000
                           --------
Result                     0001 0000 //4th bit set
```

And, `binary_number &= ~(1<<4)`:

```
Original Number     -       000X 0000 //4th bit could be a 1 or a 0; X =1/0
Mask to set 3rd bit - (AND) 1110 1111
                            --------
Result                      0000 0000 //4th bit reset
```

Answer (score 0):

If you seek efficiency the best way to do it is to define the bits individually:

```
#define BIT_0  0b00000001
#define BIT_1  0b00000010
#define BIT_2  0b00000100
#define BIT_3  0b00001000
#define BIT_4  0b00010000
#define BIT_5  0b00100000
#define BIT_6  0b01000000
#define BIT_7  0b10000000
```

and then to set the bit in a byte:

```
unsigned char byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset = 0;

//To Set bit 3
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset |= BIT_3;

//To Set Multiple bits
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset |= (BIT_3 + BIT_4 + BIT_5);
//OR
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset |= (BIT_3 | BIT_4 | BIT_5);

//To reset bit 3
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset &= ~(BIT_3);

//To reset Multiple bits
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset &= ~(BIT_3 + BIT_4 + BIT_5);
//OR
byteWhoseBitsAreSetReset &= ~(BIT_3 | BIT_4 | BIT_5);
```

Comment: That is more concise but not more "efficient." whatever "efficiency" is supposed to mean in this context.  You're just offloading the bit definitions to the preprocessor's #define statements instead of letting the compiler do the shift at compile time.

Comment: I hate to do it, but I have to agree to this fact! Yes, it's wrong on my part to call it more efficient. If I had been a politician, I would have said that it is more efficient at compile time (as if that matters!).